# Web service issues in migrating from ColdFusion 9 to 10

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm troubleshooting a problem a client is having with their migration from CF9 to CF10. A webservice call that previously worked, no longer is working. When I call it from my CF10 server, I get this error:

> C:...\cfusion\stubs\WS-853189522_2...\service.java:10: class, interface, or enum expected package ...;
>
> *The ellipses are to replace proprietary files paths and names.*

Are there any known issues with CF10 that would interfere with a webservice call that worked previously? I did find some mention of possible issues with Axis 1 calls, and when I add the new cfinvoke attributes wsversion and refreshwsdl, I get a "Unable to read WSDL from URL: .../service.asmx?WSDL" error instead of the above error. I also changed the default ws version from 2 to 1 in the CF Administrator, with no change.

Comment: I found the answer, and it turned out to be quite simple. After making the change to the default webservice version in CF Admin, I needed to restart the server. It now works, although I am curious as to why adding the wsversion attribute to the cfinvoke tag calling the webservice didn't work. My concern now is that if they add an Axis 2 webservice call in the future that they may run into this problem again.

Comment: Instead of a comment you should add your resolution as an answer to your own question. It is okay to do that here.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.

I think Adobe missed a trick by making Axis 2 the default in the ColdFusion Administrator with a new install. If they had made the default Axis 1 all would have worked fine.

Comment: I can understand why they might have done so, at least in future updates, but for the sake of legacy apps, this point in time is not a good one for doing so. That's OK, it's an easy fix.